# How to Join two columns from table A with two columns from table B - Linq join MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How can i Join two columns from `dbo.Sales Invoice Line` with two columns from `dbo.Value Entry` in linq SQL! Can anyone please help me :) thanks in advance :)

This is SQL version :

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM dbo.[Item Ledger Entry] 
 INNER JOIN 
 dbo.[Value Entry] ON dbo.[Item Ledger Entry].[Entry No_] = dbo.[Value Entry].[Item Ledger Entry No_] 

  //Start here
  INNER JOIN
  dbo.[Sales Invoice Line] ON dbo.[Value Entry].[Document No_] = dbo.[Sales Invoice Line].[Document No_] 
  AND 
  dbo.[Value Entry].[Document Line No_] = dbo.[Sales Invoice Line].[Line No_]
```

And this is linq version i end up with , but im not sure i did it in the right way!:

```
from cbr in db.Contact_Business_Relation
                join c in db.Contact on cbr.Contact_No_ equals c.Company_No_
                join sa in db.Sales_Invoice_Header on cbr.No_ equals sa.Sell_to_Customer_No_
                join sih in db.Sales_Invoice_Line on sa.No_ equals sih.Document_No_

                //Start here
                join ve in db.Value_Entry on sih.Document_No_ equals ve.Document_No_ 
                join vetwo in db.Value_Entry on sih.Line_No_ equals vetwo.Document_Line_No_
                join item in db.Item_Ledger_Entry on ve.Item_Ledger_Entry_No_ equals item.Entry_No_
```

Comment: `//Start here, but its not working` How is it not working?

Comment: @mjwills it cant execute the query and page still wating /loading for long time

Comment: @mjwills and i also not sure i did it in the right way !

Comment: So why don't you share the relevant parts of your classes with us. Are you using entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this multi-condition join by matching an object on each side of the join condition. This can be a typed object, but an anonymous object is also fine, provided that the property names match. The relevant part of your query should look something like this:

```
//Start here
join ve in db.Value_Entry on new {
   DocNo = sih.Document_No_,
   LineNo = sih.Line_No_ } equals new {
   DocNo = ve.Document_No_,
   LineNo = ve.Document_Line_No_ }
```